# What is the meaning of the following sentence: $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ have a common factor modulo $p$.

Tags: field-theory

Let $p$ a prime number. Let $P$ and $Q$ two polynomials over finite fields. What is the meaning of the following sentence:

$P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ have a common factor modulo $p$.

Comment: Well, you should say what ring $P,Q$ have coefficients in.  If $\mathbb Z$ then it just means that there is a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(x)$ divides both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ over the field with $p$ elements.  Usually one would require that $f(x)$ have degree greater than $0$.

Comment: For instance, $x^4+1$ and $x^2+5x+6$ have a common factor of $x+2$ modulo $17$ since both of them have a root at $x=-2$.

Comment: @lulu: over finite fields.

Comment: @lulu Post that as an answer. It's better than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $P(x), Q(x)$ have coefficients in the field with $p$ elements, this just means that there is a polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb F_p[x]$ which divides both of them over that field.  Generally one requires that $f(x)$ have degree $≥1$.

Example:  with $p=17$ we have $x^4+1\equiv (x+2)(x+8)(x+9)(x+15)\pmod {17}$ and of course $x^2+5x+6\equiv (x+2)(x+3)\pmod {17}$.  Thus $x^4+1$ and $x^2+5x+6$ have a common factor of $x+2$ modulo ${17}$.  Note that they do not have a common factor over $\mathbb Q$, say.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the polynomials $x^2 + 1$ and $x + 1$ as polynomials with coefficients from the two element field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of integers modulo $2$. Then since there
$$
x^2 + 1 = (x  + 1)^2
$$
those polynomials have the common factor $x+1$ modulo $2$.